# Importing trx-reports with tcm.exe fails due to: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, trx, tcm

I'm trying to import my trx reports into mtm/tfs using tcm.exe. For any reason I'm always getting this error message:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

Here is the command I used for the importing:

```
tcm testcase /import /collection:http://my.tfs.url:8090 /teamproject:myProject /storage:C:\temp\ProtractorTestResults.trx
```

I'm also not able to load the configuration using this command (same error message):

```
tcm configs /list /collection:http://my.tfs.url:8090 /teamproject:myProject
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you open MTM and connect?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to connect to TFS using MTM.

Comment: Is there some reason that you are using 8090 and not 8080?